# Java MulthiThreading Equal Cards divide with 4 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn multi-threading by implementing code snippets. The problem is to distribute cards(52) among four lists using 4 threads(13 each), please suggest better solution or correction in below code.

As this is for practice on multi-threading, I have not made much stress on naming conventions and generics (apologies for this)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class CardsDivideIntoFour {
    static final int Max = 52;
    static int val = 0;
    static Object ox = new Object();
    static List list1 = new LinkedList();
    static List list2 = new LinkedList();
    static List list3 = new LinkedList();
    static List list4 = new LinkedList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (val >= Max) {
                        break;
                    }
                    synchronized (ox) {
                        list1.add(++val);
                        System.out.println("a>  " + val);
                        ox.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            if (val >= Max) {
                                // System.out.println("t1 run finished");
                                // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            ox.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Unreachable code
                // System.out.println("t1 run finished");

            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (val >= Max) {
                        break;
                    }
                    synchronized (ox) {
                        list2.add(++val);
                        System.out.println("b>  " + val);
                        ox.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            if (val >= Max) {
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            ox.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (val >= Max) {
                        break;
                    }
                    synchronized (ox) {
                        list3.add(++val);
                        System.out.println("c> " + val);
                        ox.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            if (val >= Max) {
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            ox.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (val >= Max) {
                        break;
                    }
                    synchronized (ox) {
                        list4.add(++val);
                        System.out.println("d> " + val);
                        ox.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            if (val >= Max) {
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            ox.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        System.out.print("List1 has > ");
        for (Object o : list1) {
            System.out.print((Integer) o + ",");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("List2 has > ");
        for (Object o : list2) {
            System.out.print((Integer) o + ",");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("List3 has > ");
        for (Object o : list3) {
            System.out.print((Integer) o + ",");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("List4 has > ");
        for (Object o : list4) {
            System.out.print((Integer) o + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one implementation of `Runnable` (e.g. `CardDistributionTask implements Runnable`) should be enough. And each thread should receive a number cards to distribute. I think the approach would be to split the deck into 4 parts and let each thread distribute a part.

Comment: This example is not going to teach you very much about multi-threading. A better example might be to have one producer thread that adds cards to a `BlockingQueue`, and four consumer threads that pull from that queue and write to their own lists. This will at least give you a sense of how thread scheduling might work.

Comment: let me try with one runnable. Will implement one producer and 4 consumers using BlockingQueue

Comment: As addition to @parsifal comment, do use `ExecutorService`, `Lock` and `Condition` instead of this "native" threading.

Comment: @BheshGurung suppose if I use one Runnable , how will I get hold of list1,list2,list3,list4

Comment: You can define the constructor to take the list of cards.

Comment: @Naroji Did you check my new answer? It gives you almost the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Why re-inventing the wheel? The new Java SE 7 provides the [`Fork\Join framework`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), which does this job for you concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will read join-Fork, but I am trying to understand how I can implement using Java multi-threading low-level APIs

Comment: @Naroji Ok. Please refer to my other answer

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a field indicating the current turn of thread?

```
static int turn = 0;
```

Take a look at [the code](http://ideone.com/doTpAC).

## Details of synchronization

There are three parts of thread synchronization.

1) First, the thread must aquire the lock at `synchronized (ox)`. The thread is being in the *blocking* state, until the holder thread releases the lock, then the thread attempts to aquire the lock. If it fails again to aquire the lock, it is put again in *blocking* state.

2) When the thread aquire the lock and enter the block of `synchronized`, it must firstly determine whether it is really able to aquire the lock or wait for some operation to be done. Thus we have a loop to check if the turn is the thread's turn. If it is not, the thread puts itself in the *wait* state, saying "I must wait for the one that has the turn to complete its task". The thread then remains in the *waiting* state, until another thread awakes it with `notifyAll`. It then re-determine whether it is able to do the job, if not, it puts itself again in *waiting* state. Otherwise, it does its job.

3) At final, the thread doesn't forgest to wake up the other *waiting* threads using `notfiyAll` after finishing its task. If it forgets, the other threads will still in *waiting* state for ever. This state is called **deadlock** and may cause the program to hung up.